# 'adb devices' is not listing my phone

Tags: adb

I am trying to do a full backup of my Galaxy Note 4.1.2 phone using the adb command. t says it couldn't connect to my device. Then I did a 'adb devices' and there where no listed devices. My Windows File Explorer shows my phone and I can browse its contents.

Any ideas why the device can't be listed?

Comment: Browsing the device via Windows Explorer is not related to accessing it over ADB. Do you have USB debugging enabled in your settings? Did you install an ADB driver (or any other drivers) for your device?

Comment: do you have samsung kies installed ?!

Comment: @eldarerathis I mentioned this fact so I don't get "Are you sure it's connected?" comments!

Comment: Sorry, I honestly have no idea what you're trying to say with your last comment. Neither question I asked was "Are you sure it's connected?" - I asked if you have USB debugging enabled on your device and if you installed any ADB drivers for your device. You mentioned neither of those things, you only noted that Windows Explorer can see it (which has no relevance to ADB).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you see the device from your File Explorer doesn't mean that is should work from ADB. Most phone support standard file transfer protocols such as MTP and/or mass storage.

To use ADB you need to install the USB driver that is associated to your device. For Samsung devices you can search for downloads related to your particular device but I guess installing Kies would also do it. Then you need to enable USB debugging from the *parameters -> development* screen.

After this is done you should see you device when running *adb devices*.